# Incorrect Values within SQLDA Structure

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm having a problem with this error:

```
"Incorrect Values within SQLDA Structure"
```

I have here the following codes:

```
var
FICS00 : Treenode;
DBFICS00 : String;

begin
DBFICS00 := AdvCheckTreeView1.Items[111];
sqlquery1.SQL.Clear;
sqlquery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO USERTABLE(FICS00)');
sqlquery1.SQL.Add('VALUES (:FICS00)');
sqlquery1.Params.PArambyName('FICS00').AsBoolean := AdvCheckTreeView1.Checked[DBFICS00];
sqlquery1.ExecSQL();
end;
```

I used Firebird and Delphi Xe2

Comment: I changed my codes above. Its sqlquery1.params.parambyname and I get that Error. but When I tried to used sqlquery1.Fieldbyname It says "Field "FICS" not found"

Comment: I changed my parameter to FICS00 which is the datafield.

Comment: Your question is a kind of a chameleon .... how does this mach the initial question `sqlquery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO USERTABLE(FICS00)');
sqlquery1.SQL.Add('VALUES (:USER_CODE)');`

Comment: [Error message “Incorrect values within SQLDA structure” with Firebird and Delphi 2009](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852290/error-message-incorrect-values-within-sqlda-structure-with-firebird-and-delphi)

Comment: I just having a typo error with my question.